# Plugin definition in settings.xml is not accepting build tag

Tags: maven, spotbugs

I would like to define global plugin inside of my `Settings.xml`
file looks like:

```
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>spotbugs</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>Low</threshold>
                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.h3xstream.findsecbugs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>findsecbugs-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.10.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>spotbugs</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

unfortunatley i get:

> [WARNING] [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the
> effective settings [WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'build' (position:
> START_TAG seen ...\n      ... @5:14)  @
> /Users/gs/.m2/settings.xml, line 5, column 14 [WARNING]

is it possible to put plugin information like above into `pluginRepositries`? I would like to have global conifiguration for this plugin instead of editing every single pom.xml to use `mvm spotbugs:spotbugs`

Comment: The `settings.xml` does not allow to defined build tag see https://maven.apache.org/settings.html To define a plugin globally you can do that via a corporate pom file

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by put plugins configuration in one super/corporate pom i section:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
           ....
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
<build>
```

In order to use it all your project must have set parent to this pom.